# How to move windows between workspaces using the mouse?

Tags: gnome, mouse, gnome-shell, workspaces

I found out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> can move windows to another workspace.

Is there a way of doing that with the mouse?

Comment: Also, if you start expo (activate in compiz) you can click and drag a window (right?).

Comment: This question is actually the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can always right-click the title bar of a window and select one of the following options.

#### Move to Workspace Right

[image: workspace-moving-screenshot]
<sub>This will move the window to the workspace on the right.</sub>

#### Move to Workspace Left

[image: workspace-moving-screenshot]
<sub>This will move it to the workspace on the left. In my case, it is down due to Unity's workspace setup.</sub>

### In Unity (from 11.04 to 17.04)

#### Select "Move to Another Workspace"...

...and select the workspace you want the window to switch to

[image: workspace-moving-screenshot]
<sub>This will move it to the selected workspace.</sub>

#### Invoking the *Expose mode*

1. Clicking on the *Workspace Switcher* icon in the launcher

   [image: screenshot]
2. Hitting <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Now you only have to drag the window to the desired workspace.

Comment: How to do that for Atom text editor? Cant even click on the title bar.

Answer (score 6):

Some applications (Google Chrome and Qt based programs) the normal right click does not show the move to choices but alt-right-click does.

Comment: I ran into this problem when I changed Ubuntu versions. If you right click the menu and select "Use System Titles and Borders", you can just right click the menu and forego the alt.

Comment: Don't know whether you meant this but for me it is super (i.e. Windows key) right click that shows the extra options (not Alt).

Answer (score 3):

### GNOME Shell: Ubuntu 17.10+

On [GNOME Shell](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html.en) (default on Ubuntu 17.10+) another way is using drag-and-drop on Activities overview:

1. Open the [Activities](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities) overview (similar to expose mode).
2. Click and drag the window toward the right of the screen.
3. The [workspace selector](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces.html.en) will appear.
4. Drop the window onto an empty workspace. This workspace now contains the window you have dropped, and a new empty workspace appears at the bottom of the *workspace selector*.

You can also move windows directly between workspaces.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

With Unity (Ubuntu before 17.10): Also, if you want a bit more control over the whole affair: you can install CCSM

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

from here you can assign your own shortcuts.